# React - input checkbox onchange won't fire first time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

The behaviour of a checkbox input is not being very reliable.

I'm setting the state of a checkbox based on state from the store. This works fine. However sometimes checking the checkbox will not fire the `onchange`. Checking the box a second time will fire, however the UI will display the wrong state as it misfired the first time.

I'm using NextJS. This mostly happens when loading the page for the first time, or hard refresh.

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import _cloneDeep from 'lodash/cloneDeep';

export default function Privacy() {
    const consentObj = useSelector((state) => state.cookieOptions);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const analyticsConsent = useSelector(
        (state) => state.cookieOptions.analytics
    );

    function toggleConsentAnalytics() {
        // this function will not fire on first input onchange
        const newSettings = _cloneDeep(consentObj);
        newSettings.analytics = !consentObj.analytics;

        dispatch({ type: 'SET_COOKIE_OPTIONS', payload: newSettings });
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div className={css.settingContainer}>
                <strong>Analytics cookie</strong>
                <label>
                    <div className={css.switchWrap}>
                        {analyticsConsent ? 'On' : 'Off'}
                        <span className={css.switch}>
                            <input
                                defaultChecked={analyticsConsent}
                                onChange={() => toggleConsentAnalytics()}
                                type="checkbox"
                            />
                            <span className={css.slider}></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

I've removed what I think is irrelevant code from my example.

I have an identical flow using a Class component and it works as expected. But it seems that we should be moving away from this into functional components so would very much like to solve this rather than revert to a Class!

Thanks in advance for any assistance

Comment: try using onClick  instead

Comment: `I've removed what I think is irrelevant code from my example`....can you make a minimum stackblitz that reproduces your behavior?

Comment: Can you verify that analyticsConsent is never undefined upon first render. Try to console.log it

Comment: @Domino987 it looks like to begin with the state is loaded with the default state, the loads the actual current state.

Comment: @TiagoCoelho This actually worked. if you make it an answer I'll be happy to select it as the correct one

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `onClick` instead of `onChange` and it will work properly.

This has nothing to do with react, but with how the onchange event works in html.

Comment: Any idea why it doesn't work? I'm interested to learn why onChange doesn't fire in this case.

Answer (score 2):

to make sure you have the right state of your checkbox, you can just use the checked attribute:

```html
<input type="checkbox" 
  checked={myValue} 
  onChange={(e) => setMyValue(e.target.checked)} 
/>
```